# Jacobi in Parallel in Julia

Tags: arrays, parallel-processing, julia, distributed-computing, distributed

I'm trying to run this Jacobi code in parallel, but it's not working:

```
using Distributed
addprocs(2)
@everywhere using LinearAlgebra
@everywhere using DistributedArrays

@everywhere  n=5
@everywhere  m=n^2
I=Diagonal(ones(n,n))
A = Tridiagonal([fill(-1, n-2); -1], fill(2, n), [-1; fill(-1, n-2);])
A=kron(A,I)+kron(I,A)
b=ones(m,1)
x=ones(m,1)
d=ones(m,1)

A=distribute(A; dist=(2,1))
b=distribute(b; dist=(2,1))
x=distribute(x; dist=(2,1))
d=distribute(d; dist=(2,1))
D = distribute(ones(size(A,1),1); dist=(nworkers(), 1))  
@everywhere Δx=[]

@sync @distributed for z in 1:2
    for i in 1:8
        D_local=localpart(D)
        x_local=localpart(x)
        A_local=localpart(A)
        b_local=localpart(b)
            for j in 1:16
                if i!== j
                    global xx
                    x_local = x_local + inv(D_local)[i,i].*(b_local - A_local*x_local)
                end
            end
    end
    return xx
end
```

Comment: I replaced the image by the code in your "answer" -- they are the same, right?

Comment: And please add information about what exactly "is not working".

Comment: To add to that, please include the error message you are getting (if you are getting one), and what the expected outcome of running this code would be. Otherwise, no one will be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is Okay  I got it already.thank you

```
using Distributed
addprocs(2)
@everywhere using LinearAlgebra
@everywhere using DistributedArrays

@everywhere  n=6
@everywhere  m=n^2
I=Diagonal(ones(n,n))
A = Tridiagonal([fill(-1, n-2); -1], fill(2, n), [-1; fill(-1, n-2);])
A=kron(A,I)+kron(I,A)
b=ones(m,1)
x=ones(m,1)
d=ones(m,1)

A=distribute(A; dist=(2,1))
b=distribute(b; dist=(2,1))
x=distribute(x; dist=(2,1))
d=distribute(d; dist=(2,1))
D = distribute(4*ones(size(A,1),1); dist=(2, 1))
maxit = 100
for z in 1:maxit
    @sync @distributed for t in 1:2
        for i in 1:length(localindices(A)[1])
            localpart(x)[i] =  localpart(x)[i] + ( localpart(b)[i] -  localpart(A*x)[i])./localpart(D)[i]
        end
        println(x)
    end
end

using Plots
plot(convert(Array,x))

x
```